# How to pass command output as several arguments to another command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, shell-scripting

I have a command that produce a output like this:

$./command1

word1 word2 word3

I want to pass this three words as arguments to another command like this:

$ command2 word1 word2 word3

How to pass command1 output as three different arguments $1 $2 $3 to command2 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `xargs`, with the `-t` flag `xargs` will be verbose and prints the commands it executes:

```
./command1 | xargs -t -n1 command2
```

`-n1` defines the maximum arguments passed to every call of `command2`. This will execute:

```
command2 word1
command2 word2
command2 word3
```

If you want all as argument of one call of `command2` use that:

```
./command1 | xargs -t command2
```

That calls command2 with 3 arguments:

```
command2 word1 word2 word3
```

Comment: What if the output of command1 is longer than `ARG_MAX` ? I have a scenario where I am passing contents of a file to a function.

Comment: Big thanks ! the -n1 option saved the day ! Below is the commands I was trying  jq -r '.repositories[].repositoryUri' | xargs -t -n1 docker pull

Answer (score 4):

You want 'command substitution', i.e: embed output of one command in anouther

```
command2 $(command1)
```

Traditionally this can also be done as:

```
command2 `command1`
```

but this usage isn't normally recommended, as you can't nest them.

For example:

```
test.sh:
#!/bin/bash
echo a b c
```

test2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $2
```

USE:

```
./test2.sh $(./test.sh)
b
```

Comment: If I do that, it is passing command1 output as one single argument, not like three different:
$command2 $(cat output_from_command1)

Comment: ah right, one sec... btw cat isn't needed in that one you put there.

Comment: Works for me. If my command2 echos $2 (i,e: second argument) i get "word2" as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this help you

command1 | xargs command2